# How to open set this to any object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a function like this

```
function foo(a) {
    $(this).html(a);
}

var r = $("#hello");
```

and I can't change the function `foo`, what can I do to call `foo` using `r`, such that inside `foo`, `this` will refer to the object selected by `r`?

I tried this

```
r.each(function(i, x) {
    foo(1);
});
```

but it did not work. The `this` referred to the `window` object.

Comment: Should be able to do `foo.call(r)`.

Comment: What about passing additional parameters?

Comment: `r.each` will always run over one element only. jQuery finds the first only as ids have to be unique

Comment: Then you would use `foo.call(r, param1, param2, ...)` or `foo.apply(r, [param1, param2, ...])`.

Comment: @baao It just means it will be a set of one. `.each` will still work.

Comment: @MikeC sorry, wrong wording.-- You're right

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ That works assuming they want the jQuery collection object to be `this` instead of each individual element which is what you get using `each`.

Comment: @MikeC: I didn't think of that -- your answer is definitely more explanatory and correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when you call a function by itself, `this` will be set to the global object (or `undefined`) unless the function scope was previously bound.

To use the function the way you wanted, write it like this:

```
r.each(foo);
```

That will pass the function directly and ensure `this` is set to the same value as it would be if the body of `foo` was inside of your anonymous function.

If you want to pass additional parameters to `foo` which are not passed by `each`, you will have to call it using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
r.each(function() {
  foo.call(this, 1);
});
```

Comment: Can you include support for parameters.

Comment: @omega Only if you want `this` to be equal to `r` instead of the individual elements that `each` runs over. They're not the same thing.